# Embedding PDF graphics with TeXShop causes issues

Tags: errors

I'm trying to import PDF graphics (created in Illustrator CS3) into a TeX document.

Here is the code for including the figure:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp] %  figure placement: here, top, bottom, or page
       \centering
         \includegraphics[width=3.5in]{BPQM01PSa.pdf} 
        \caption{caption..}.}
       \label{fig:BPQM ptps}
    \end{figure}
```

The following error message appears

> id=25, 845.0471pt x 597.50829pt>  ! Extra }, or
>   forgotten \endgroup. \@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup
>
> \color@endbox
>      l.298     \end{figure}
>
> ?

(I don't know how to post a pdf graphic to this site, of someone knows of an easy way to post one to the web i'll provide a link to it).

After clicking the the error console-log window the glitch *sometimes* rights itself and a pdf document is produced with the graphic embedded.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say

```
\caption{caption..}
```

instead of

```
\caption{caption..}.}
```

Just one parenthesis too much.

In such cases, editors with bracket highlighting do help.

This is btw no editor problem.

Comment: thanks! bit embarrassing that it was just a syntax error...